# Getting a linechart entry label MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I have a line chart with entries that the user can click on via line chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener. Is there a way that I can programmatically get the label of whichever entry is clicked? Or is there some other way of achieving this in my code?

```
private void chartAreaClickResponse(LineChart lineChart) {
    lineChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
          //get the label of the entry here

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, in case anyone needs to know this in the future.Simply add the following line under "onValueSelected":

```
    @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
      String label = dataSets.get(h.getDataSetIndex()).getLabel(); //add this
    }
```

In this case, dataSets is the "ILineDataSet" used to populate the line chart